# Can Traditional and Roth 401k be withdrawn in a ratio to minimize taxes in retirement?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k, withdrawal, roth-401k

I've seen posts claiming that if you have a mix of pre-tax and after-tax savings in a 401k, the pre-tax money can be withdrawn up to the threshold of the top of the current 12% tax bracket and after-tax money can be withdrawn in the same year for any additional needed income. This strategy would limit your marginal tax rate to 12% in retirement. Are there any IRS rules that would prevent this?

Some people say that the money has to be withdrawn from the same plan proportionally. If you have $100,000 in pre-tax money and $100,000 in after-tax money all withdraws would have to be 50% pre-tax and 50% after-tax dollars. If that is true, could the money be transferred to separate IRA and Roth IRA accounts to get around that?

Edit: It has been pointed out that I was misunderstanding the meaning of after-tax money. I am interested in any rules governing withdrawals from Traditional and Roth 401k accounts and was unaware of the third category of after-tax money in a Traditional 401k.

Comment: Don't confuse "after-tax money in Traditional IRA" (which actually means non-zero cost basis) with Roth accounts.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thanks for bringing that to my attention. I had no idea that after-tax money could be contributed to a Traditional 401k or IRA.

Comment: If you have one or more _trad_ IRA(s) and basis (post-tax contributions) in any, the basis is aggregated over all accounts and when you withdraw the basis is used pro-rata regardless of which account(s) you withdraw from -- this might be what you heard from 'some people'. However putting basis in a trad, unless followed immediately by a 'backdoor' Roth conversion, is usually a bad strategy and IME rarely done.

Answer (score 3):

You are not bound in any way how much money you withdraw from which retirement account. Any combination is possible, and you can (and *should*) optimize the split for taxes.

There are some special plans for early retirees under 59.5 and other situations where you can make 'substantial regular withdrawal' from specific accounts; those require predefined amounts, but only *from those accounts*. You can still withdraw from other accounts whatever you feel like.

Comment: Traditional IRAs are subject to a required minimum distribution once you are 70.5